# How to set custom reports directory in gradle3.3

Tags: gradle

By default, Gradle generates reports under `build\reports` directory. I want to change this default location.

I tried using `destinationDir` property but getting below error

`Could not set unknown property 'destinationDir' for task ':test'`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What gradle plugin you are using?

Comment: @MohammadTabbara java & idea